# What's the vault code?

Tags: full-of-stars

In the IOS game, Full of Stars, there is a section when you reach the Quantum Comms Station with a vault in it. Here you are told that the vault contains a shortcut to the Blue Sector, but you are not told the last three digits of the code as the "Laser fire had destroyed the plastic card". So naturally I tried to guess, but I lost a few crew to the turret, and couldn't afford to loose anymore, so I moved on.

However, on my next play through, I died going through Heaven's Gate, I wanted to know the code, so I Googled what it was but could only find [this page.](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?s=59dad3138328d38cea2ec673d114ccff&p=4001515) It didn't say what the code was, but it did tell me that I could "Look for it in Tortuga", but when I came here I couldn't seem to find it either.

So what is the code to the vault, and where can I find it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

733197 - 438. The first few numbers are given to you when you inspect the body at the Q-COS station. If you go in to scavenge supplies you get 700 idium free, or some free idium crystals (random). Then you have the option to go to the vault or leave. Then options to inspect the turret, the body, and read the first few numbers of the code. You are only asked to enter the last 3 numbers.

Once you enter the vault you get to unlock another place. So you get the option to go to the corporate battlefield, Tortuga station (very hard) and vivid nebula (hard).

Comment: Where abouts are the last three digits found though?

Answer (score 4):

[Gamble with the pirates in Tortuga enough](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showpost.php?p=4001557&postcount=59)
 and you'll be offered a chance to win an unburnt keycard with the code. Every visit the vault after that and you'll have it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The last three digits of the vault code is **438**

Comment: Please fill your answer with useful stuff, rather than a bunch of dots. If you can't enter something, it generally means that there's more to add, not that you should work around the restriction. For example, you haven't answered half the question, and that'd probably meet the required character count.